# Trying to get a substring using regex in Python / pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, substring, data-cleaning

I know this may seem stupid but I've been looking everywhere and trying with regex and split in vain. My script never works for all type of string I have on my data set.

I have this column that contains raw data that look like (three cases):

```
20181223-FB-BOOST-AAAA-CC Auchy-Les-Mines - Père Noel
20161224-FB-BOOST-SSSS-CC LeMarine - XXX XXX
20161223-FB-BOOST-XXXX-CC Bonjour le monde - Blah blah
```

So what I want to do is to get the strings in the middle after CC and right before "-". I wrote a script that did work for the 2nd case but never the other two :

```
1st case: Auchy-Les-Mines
2nd case: LeMarine
3rd case: Bonjour le monde
```

Here is the regex that I used but never works for all cases: regex = `r"\s\b.*-."`

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `str.extract(r'-CC\s*(.*?)\s+-')`? See https://regex101.com/r/2LagAy/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you don't need to put in the whitespace at the beginning, a better approach to that regex would be "-CC.*?\s-"

Comment: @PabloAlvarez See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54650702/3832970) where I explain why it  is there

Comment: You can use split method and select 2nd index, if your data has this structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You my use

```py
df['Col'].str.extract(r'-CC\s+(.*?)\s+-')
```

If there can be line breaks between the two delimiters, add the `s`/`dotall` flag or use `[\w\W]`/`[\s\S]`/`[\d\D]` instead of a `.`:

```py
df['Col'].str.extract(r'(?s)-CC\s+(.*?)\s+-')
#                       ^^^^
df['Col'].str.extract(r'-CC\s+([\w\W]*?)\s+-')
#                              ^^^^^^
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2LagAy/4).

**Pattern details**

- `-CC` - a literal substring
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 (this value will be returned by `.str.extract`): any 0+ chars other than newline, as few as possible
- `\s+` -  1+ whitespaces (`+` is important here)
- `-` - a hyphen

The fact that there are `\s+` patterns on both ends of `(.*?)` will make sure the result is already stripped from whitespace regardless of how many whitespaces there were.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you so much and thank especially for explaining the patter details! U just saved my day! thanks :) !

Comment: Already done :) ! Otherwise, there was one more problem haha! I have some rows that looks like: 20180223-FB-BOOST-XXX-CC Vitrolles - 110 - St Valentin where I only want to retrieve "Vitrolles" I get this output instead using the regex u suggested:  Vitrolles - 110 so I fixed it using the following regex: 

(r'-CC\s+(.*?)\s+-[^1-9]')

(Apparently, it didn't go green cuz they said I need more reputation to be able to vote :( )

Comment: @helloworld See the latest update, no need for `[^1-9]`. Please consider clicking the grey tick mark on the left to accept the solution. Do not pay attention at the `1` on the left, it does not mean the answer is accepted.

Comment: Same problem! It reutns numbers which is not the the results expected! [^1-9] still does the job tho  ! Wdu think?

Comment: @helloworld Ok, that is already fine-tuning that only you know how to perform. So, there should be no digit after `-`, right? So, it seems `r'-CC\s+(.*?)\s+-'` does what you need already, but you may also use `r'-CC\s+(.*?)\s+-(?!\s*\d)'` to avoid matching `-` that is followed with 0+ whitespaces and a digit.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it rather simple with:

```
result = df.raw_data.str.extract(r'-CC (.*) -')
```